# How can I make a drive accessible to Linux / Bash subsystem on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a laptop which I've dual-booted with Ubuntu and Windows 10.

My goal is to use a bash shell inside windows to access the linux partition.

Inside Windows, I've installed the Linux subsystem and also used Ext2Fsd to create a D:// drive for the Linux system.

In the Bash shell, though, I can only see the C:// drive. How can I access the D:// drive?

I tried creating a shortcut in windows, but it makes `.lnk` file that I'm not sure how to follow in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I access the D:// drive?

It will only be pseudo-mounted if it is fixed drive and formatted as NTFS.

> Note that we don't currently support mounting drives in WSL - we pseudo-mount fixed NTFS drives in your machine, but cannot currently mount removable (e.g. USB) drives or non-NTFS drives

Source - comment by [Richard Turner](https://superuser.com/users/78527/richard-turner) who works for the Microsoft WSL team.

> In order for a drive to show up under /mnt/ it must meet the following
>   criteria:
>
> 1. The drive must be a fixed drive
> 2. The drive must be formatted to NTFS.

This has been raised as an issue: [Drives other than C: are not mounted in /mnt #1079](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1079). It is still marked as "Open".

> To facilitate interoperability with Windows, WSL uses the DrvFs file system. WSL automatically mounts all fixed drives with supported file systems under /mnt, such as /mnt/c, /mnt/d, etc. Currently, only NTFS and ReFS volumes are supported.

Source [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/)

Comment: I'm kind of having a hard time turning this into an actionable plan. Are you saying that if the drive is Ext, it's impossible to mount it? I already have the drive in Windows mounted at D:// using the Ext2Fsd program. I just need to add it to the Bash. And where is this `mount` command run? Linux or Windows?

Comment: @maxpleaner As far as I know yes. The mount command is run in bash. I don't have WIndows 10 so I can't confirm the bug report.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Note that WSL doesn't currently support manually `mount`ing drives. WSL itself pseudo-mounts your fixed NTFS drives, but users cannot manually do this yet.

Comment: @RichardTurner Oh. That's good to know. Will the fixed drive limitation be fixed soon? I will update the answer.

Comment: It's something we're keen to remedy, but requires some additional engineering that we have to prioritize and schedule. No timeline to share at this point. Thx.

Comment: @RichardTurner Thanks. It's good to have you on board answering WSL questions! :)

Comment: @maxpleaner Answer updated, `mount`ing drives is not currently supported by WSL.